# How to get Javascript on key press call to return html text without being in a text box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a very simple Javascript program that will essentially start as a blank page, but when the user presses a key (ideally space but it doesn't really matter) it will print a large text that flashes in 0.2 second intervals, and i can't quite figure out how to go about making a call that doesn't require including a text box like I've seen on other sites. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://codepen.io/asellenrick/pen/QgKPrQ?editors=0010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the event handler to the body tag.

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("keypress", function() {
  //your code goes here
});
```

Comment: Any idea on how to add colour/font size/positioning though? because if I try to use CSS reffering to the body it does nothing

Comment: Can I see the html you are using?